# I want to know which one is mostly used template driven forms or reactive forms?

Tags: angular

I am new in angular and confused between the template driven forms and reactive forms. i just want to know which should i need to learn that mostly used?

Answer (score 0):

In mast case Real life cases reactive forms are normally used because they enable you to develop forms that perform some form validation on the front end before sending the values to the server with minimal code.
And form validation is a necessity for Web apps that will be used by users.

Answer (score 0):

Request to use Reactive forms. This enable you to write clean template with validation comes in major role.
This may help you, the logs from angular.

https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/difference-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms-angular

Answer (score 0):

Unpopular opinion here. Don’t just follow the crowd, start by using template driven forms and if you find something you can’t do let us know (I haven’t found anything you can’t do with them that you can do in reactive forms). I’ll argue that they are 100x more readable and simpler to understand and maintain. But choose your own path, this like everyone else has given, is just an opinion.